# DateTime formula field to compare to a specific time

Tags: formula, date, datetime, time

I am creating an entry criteria for a milestone to kickoff. A separate workflow rule populates a DateTime field (RMA_Time__c) with NOW(). When RMA_Time__c is populated and the populated time is before 2:30 PM EST, the milestone should start.

How can I write this as a formula? I am having an extremely hard time trying to figure out a formula to compare a current DateTime field to a specific time value.

Answer (score 1):

Tinkered around with this for a bit and here's one workable method. Have a field updated to today's date, have a second time based workflow activate 14 hours after today's date field. That will reliably kick off a process at 2pm according to your org time, whole hours only allowed unfortunately.

For your second request though for a comparison of date time for current date.
DateTimeValue takes a literal string, so you can pass it the required date, add the specific time required for the comparison:
`IF(NOW() < DateTimeValue("2016-11-09 09:30:00"),'true','false')`

edit: just a reminder that if you're trying to trigger something from a formula, formula changes do not kick off workflow recalculations.